# Elon Musk biography: who is the intended audience and how would you describe the tone?

Tags: ashlee-vance, elon-musk-tesla-spacex-quest, biography

In Elon Musk's biography, *Elon Musk: Tesla, SpaceX, and the Quest for a Fantastic Future*, who can be identified as the intended audience besides from Elon's critics, admirers, and wanna-be entrepreneurs?

Also, how would you describe Ashlee Vance's tone? Is this a good answer: admiring yet ambivalent? Candid/frank and colloquial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Elon's critics, admirers, and wanna-be entrepreneurs" is a pretty broad category, I think just saying the intended audience is merely people who are interested in Musk.

In terms of tone, I would say candid and colloquial. There is a moment where Vance describes Musk repeatedly asking him [Vance] if he thought he [Musk] was crazy. I feel like Vance leaving this in the book shows that he wants people to understand Musk but also to realize that Musk is just as human as the rest of us are.